# Naive ElasticNet in the glmnet package

Tags: glmnet, elastic-net

In the R package glmnet, does it calculate the Naive form of ElasticNet or is the output rescaled with the term (1 + lambda)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the glmnet package utilizes the cyclical coordinate descent method to find an elasticnet solution for GLMs as described in [Friedman, et al. 2010](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper).

An earlier package written by Zou & Hastie, [elasticnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elasticnet/), calculates elasticnet solutions (including the naive elasticnet) for least squares models using the LARS-EN algorithm detailed in their [2005 paper](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf).